# pyzmq - zmq_req can I have one context and use several sockets?

Tags: python, message-queue, benchmarking, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm currently working on a Benchmark project, where I'm trying to stress the server out with zmq requests.

I was wondering what would be the best way to approach this,  I was thinking of having a context to create a socket and push it into a thread, in which I would send request and wait for responses in each thread respectively, but I'm not too sure this is possible with python's limitations.

More over, would it be the same socket for all threads, that is, if I'm waiting for a response on one thread (With it's own socket), would it be possible for another thread to catch that response?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Test flow logic would be like this:

Client socket would use zmq.REQ.
Client sends message.
Client waits for a response.
If no response, client reconnects and tries again until limit.

I'd like to scale this operation up to any number of clients, preferring not to deal with Processes unless performance wise the difference is significant..

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"...can I have one context and use several sockets?"*

Oh sure you can.

Moreover, you can have several `Context()`-instances, each one managing  <sub>... *almost*...</sub>  any number of `Socket()`-instances, each `Socket()`-instance's methods may get called from one and only one python-thread ( a Zen-of-Zero rule: **zero-sharing** ).

Due to known GIL-lock re-**`[SERIAL]`**-isation of all the thread-based code-execution flow, this still has to and will wait for acquiring the GIL-lock ownership, which in turn permits a GIL-lock owner ( and nobody else ) to execute a fixed amount of python instructions, before it re-releases the GIL-lock to some other thread...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
So, would it be wise for me to open 10k sockets in the same thread, and loop through them for each to send a message and then for each to wait for a response?

Or on the other hand - I can open a process for each worker, send it a socket, and his job would be to send a message and wait for a response. (10k of these).

Comment: That pretty depends on what you aim to test. Scaling is a strong feature of the ZeroMQ toolbox. Python restrictions remain. GIL-lock is the known re-**`[SERIAL]`**-iser trick on how to principally avoid any *kind*-or-*form* of a **`[CONCURRENT]`**-flow of code-execution. So, the **ZeroMQ is definitely not a blocker** in going forwards in this direction.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I've been lingering around with this for a while - always finding a new limit for my client, and can't seem to open new sockets.
I've tried multiple contexts in different processes, and I've also tried to bring up the max_socket limit of these contexts.
This brought me to about 8000~ sockets for the application. Now, I know we can do better than that - I'm just not sure how. any thoughts?